# How To Insert 3 Characters From Another Column In Same Table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I used this query:

```
SELECT
    nipk,
    nipk_urut
FROM db_duk.tb_kontrak;

INSERT INTO db_duk.tb_kontrak (nipk_urut)
SELECT RIGHT(db_duk.tb_kontrak(nipk), 3)
FROM db_duk.tb_kontrak;
```

But I've got the following error:

```
1305 FUNCTION db_duk.tb_kontrak does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following syntax should work:

```
INSERT INTO db_duk.tb_kontrak (nipk_urut)
SELECT RIGHT(nipk, 3)
FROM db_duk.tb_kontrak;
```

But I don't know if this makes logical sense.  If you intended to *replace* each value with just the first three letters, then you would instead want to do an *update*, something like this:

```
UPDATE db_duk.tb_kontrak
SET nipk_urut = RIGHT(nipk, 3)
-- WHERE <some condition>
```

**Update:**

From your comments it sounds like you want to create a new column `nipk_urut` and then populate it with the last 3 characters from the already-existing `nipk` column.  You can try a statement similar to the following to create this column:

```
ALTER TABLE db_duk.tb_kontrak ADD COLUMN nipk_urut VARCHAR(50);
```

Then, do the above `UPDATE` to populate the new column.

Comment: Thanks @Tim for your help but its still not working.

Comment: `but its still not working` ... _what_ isn't working?  You need to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: When I use `INSERT INTO db_duk.tb_kontrak (nipk_urut) SELECT RIGHT(nipk, 3) FROM db_duk.tb_kontrak;` there is show another error code 1364 field 'nipk' doesn't have a default value. And when I use `UPDATE db_duk.tb_kontrak SET nipk = RIGHT(nipk, 3)` show error code 1175 you are using safe update mode and...

Comment: @F4DHL1 Have a look my updated `UPDATE` statement.  I _think_ what you are trying to do is _update_ the `nipk_urut` column as the first three letters of the `nipk` column.  In this case, you don't want to insert, you want to update.

Comment: I was create a new column (nipk_urut), and I wanna insert it with data _last three characters_ from nipk.

Comment: Then create the column and use my `UPDATE` query at the end of my answer.  To be clear here, you _don't_ want to _insert_, you want to _update_.  Inserting means creating completely new records.  In your case, you already have the record, you just want to assign a value to a new column.

Comment: Thanks @Tim it is working when I uncheck Safe Update (preferences) Workbench.

Comment: @F4DHL1 Always an annoying feature, but glad you found a way to work around it.  Actually, doing updates without any `WHERE` clause _are_ generally a bad thing, and a code smell, but in this case you know exactly what you are doing, so it isn't dangerous.